# Eloquent query hasManyThrough in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 3 models

Event - table('events')
Shift - table('shifts')
Workedtime - table('workedtimes')

and I can call `event->shifts->workedtimes`, all is fine there.

And now I want to make a query to get all Events where (Auth) user has worked.

Something like this:

```
Event::with('workedtimes')->where('workedtimes.uid', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

But this doesn't work. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all events where authenticated user has worked you need to use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
$events = Event::whereHas('workedtimes', function($q) {
    $q->where('uid', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for 
 [Constraing eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Query:

```
   Event::with(['workedtimes' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('uid', Auth::user()->id );
    }])->get();
```

Comment: i copy pasted your answer and i got an error....then i copy pasted the answer from Alexey and it worked right away... :(

Comment: @lewis4u it's ok. but, it shouldnot give the error. what error you got?

Comment: I have tried again and actually it's not a functional error but instead of getting only the events where user worked i get ALL events...with your query i get 122 events and with Alexeys code i get 9

Comment: @lewis4u you got your answer, `whereHas()` is correct. btw this gives all the events and only the workedtimes of the authenticated user.

Comment: Ok i see. Well that was the problem. I wanted only events where user has worked. Problem solved. I hope it will help others too!